# Add array on subprogram in java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to make a subprogram to search, if there is a given string in an array. I want the subprogram to have as requirements the name and the array. How can I achieve that?

My subprogram is:

```
static int findElement(String a, String array){
     for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
         if (array.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
             System.out.println(i);
             return i;
         }   
         else return 0;
     }        
}
```

I have of course errors since it doesn't accept the array as I have inserted it.

Comment: It's not because you call it `array` that it *is* an array ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a typo:

```
static int findElement(String a, String array)
```

I think you meant:

```
static int findElement(String a, String[] array)
```

Also your program has multiple issues with it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    if (array.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
        System.out.println(i);
        return i;
    }   
    else return 0;
}
```

You don't want to return as soon as one element doesn't match, you want to return when all don't match. 0 is an index, typically you return -1. To get a value from an array, you use brackets. Strings don't have a method `getName()`. You use `array.length` to get the length of an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
        return i;
    }   
}
return -1;
```

Guessing from your program, I'm assuming you mistyped the arguments and might want something like this, with a Collection and an object type:

```
static int findElement(String a, List<Person> array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        if (array.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
            return i;
        }   
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: and change `array.get(i)` to `array[i]`

Comment: I ve corrected it but again it says that the .size() and .get(i) are wrong. the error message is "Cannot find symbol"

Comment: @user3587250 I've updated. I have two versions now. If you're passing in an array, use the top one. If you were passing in a Collection of objects with a `getName()` method, use the second.

Comment: @user3587250 If this question helps you, you should accept it to tell future users that it's helpful.

Comment: @user3587250 Glad I could help! Out of curiosity, did you use the top or bottom one? Array or collection?